# How to make sure the data is available before rendering the view in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have two components, Blog and Posts. Posts are inside the Blog component. Data doesn't show under posts view when using services only for the first time. If I go and forth b/w two different views, then data comes up. So, how can I stop the view from rendering before the data is not loaded?

I am trying to fetch data from the following API (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts). Fetching works fine if I use the HTTP get directly in the component like the following,

```
this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .map((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .subscribe((data) => {
        // console.log(data);
        this.posts =  data;
    });
```

But the problem arises when i move the code to services.

I have a blog service,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class BlogService {
  posts = [];

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  fetchAllPosts() {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .map((response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .subscribe((data) => {
          // console.log(data);
          this.posts = data;
        });
  }

  getAllPosts() {
    // console.log(this.posts);
    return this.posts.slice();
  }

}
```

I'm calling fetchAllPosts() from the blog component,

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.blogService.fetchAllPosts();
}
```

Then inside the postsComponent, I'm calling getAllPosts().

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.posts = this.blogService.getAllPosts();
    console.log(this.posts);
}
```

Following is the blog component,

```
<div class="container">
    <app-posts></app-posts>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the markup of the component can you list that

Comment: Use route resolvers. This is what they are for.

Answer (score 1):

***NOTE : You should avoid using `.subscribe()` in service***

```
export class BlogService {
  posts = [];

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  fetchAllPosts() {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .map((response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
  }

  getAllPosts() {
    // console.log(this.posts);
    return this.posts.slice();                   // I don;t know why are you using .slice() here. It should be return this.posts();
  }
}
```

## PostComponent

```
posts:[];                                       // I believe you use this posts object in PostComponent template

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.posts = this.blogService.getAllPosts();
    console.log(this.posts);
}

// if above block doesn't work for you , you can use setTimeOut()



ngAfterViewInit() {
        setTimeout(()=>{
           this.posts = this.blogService.getAllPosts();
           console.log(this.posts);
        },500)

    }
```

---

## BlogComponent

```
constructor(private bgService:BlogService){       // added service
                  blogService
                  .fetchAllPosts()
                  .subscribe((data) => {
                      // console.log(data);
                      this.bgService.posts = data; // look at here, this will update posts object 
                   });

}
```

Comment: So, how can we keep the component clean?

Comment: Probably this is the answer which I showed you here.

Comment: It *does* make sense to use the subscribe in the service if the service is designed to retain the data. So if the service holds the data and shares it with the other components, then it needs to subscribe.

Comment: @micronyks so subscribe should always be in the component.

Comment: @micronyks with this way how can we share the same data b/w the different components?

Comment: @DeborahK. Nope. Look at my answer and see how have I used it to update the variable defined in service by using `.subscribe()` in component.You should avoid it. its not recommended to use `.subscribe()` in service.

Comment: @mbaljeetsingh. if you observe it deeply , you will find that I'm updating `posts object` of the service in component via `this.bgService.posts = data;` line. here` this.bgService.posts` means `posts object` of `service` only.

Comment: @micronyks tried your answer, still data not showing when opening blog page for the first time. You just moved the subscribe from the service to the blog component, right?

Comment: look at post and blog component code again. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `*ngIf` as below,

```
<div class="container">
     <div *ngIf="posts?.length > 0">
          <app-posts></app-posts>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the posts variable is only available inside <app-posts>

Comment: @mbaljeetsingh update the post with that mark up. use this condition inside that component.

Comment: But how can I make sure that I'm doing it after the call to fetchAllPosts() inside the blog component

Comment: @Aravind you have been in SO for quite a while people wont comment after dv . Leave that

Comment: @mbaljeetsingh I didn't get you. so what is the structure of the components

Comment: @RahulSingh why is the downvote. it should be for a reason. to whom ever down voted

Comment: <app-blog><app-posts></app-posts></app-blog>, then I'm using fetchAllPosts inside blogComponent(app-blog), so can't assign the posts to the variable here as the data is still to be loaded.

Comment: @Aravind i get that but you know that once someone gives a dv he or she won't ever return to that question leave that and move on

Comment: @Aravind, I don't know who downvoted, but I just upvoted. Can you suggest something?

Answer (score 0):

So ... one more option for you. This allows the service to retain the data and share it with the other parts of the application:

```
@Injectable()
export class BlogService {
  private _posts()  = [];

  get posts() {
    return _posts;
  }

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  fetchAllPosts() {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .map((response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .subscribe((data) => {
          // console.log(data);
          this.posts = data;
        });
  }
}
```

By using a getter instead of a method (such as the getAllPosts), the component can bind to this property and the data will be bound as soon as it arrives and is set by the http get.

The **PostComponent** is then:

```
   get posts() {
      return this.blogService.posts;
   }
```

Instead of the ngOnInit code you have.

That way you can bind to posts anywhere in the html for the PostComponent. The value will originally be undefined, so you will need to use the technique shown by @aravid and ensure the HTML can handle the undefined.

When the data arrives from the server, the change detection will ensure that the value is updated in the bound properties.

I have a plunker that demonstrates this technique here: https://plnkr.co/edit/BZT2oe8YmRS717lN0nPh?p=preview

Comment: I'd not recommend to use `.subscribe` in service. Any ways from component you can update `Blogservice's posts object` as shown in my answer. Its strongly not recommended.

Comment: Asking the same question as the OP ... how then does one centralize storage/sharing of the retrieved data? I agree that `.subscribe` is recommended to be used in the component if the component is the one actually getting the data. But if the **service** is getting the data and sharing it with a set of components, it seems that the service needs to subscribe. Is there another way?

Comment: @DeborahK, As I said in the aravind's comment, I don't have access to posts variable in the blog component. So can't use the following:
    <div *ngIf="posts?.length > 0">
        <app-posts></app-posts>
    </div>

Comment: @DeborahK yes. You can update service object (which is shared cross the application or components) via component as shown in my answer. or else there are ways to use RXjs library.

Comment: Just inject the service and then you'll have access to the posts variable. Consider building a plunker that more clearly defines your constraints.